# Why is the animation delay not working?

Tags: css, less, css-animations

I have 5 elements with `.intro-items` class and I want each of them have .5s animation delay more than first element.

I used this code but it doesn't work.

```
.animation-delay(@delay) {
-webkit-animation-delay : @delay s;
animation-delay         : @delay s;
}

.generate-delay(4);

.generate-delay(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .intro-items:nth-child(@{i}) {

     .animation-delay(@i*.5)
  }
  .generate-delay(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

What I get in CSS

```
.intro-items:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5 s;
   animation-delay: 0.5 s;
 }
.intro-items:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1 s;
 animation-delay: 1 s;
}
 .intro-items:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5 s;
  animation-delay: 1.5 s;
 }
.intro-items:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2 s;
 animation-delay: 2 s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why is the delay not working?**

There is no problem with Less loop. The actual problem is with the way the `animation-delay` value is being set through the code and how it differs from the expected value.

As per CSS spec, for any time value there should be no space between the numeric and the units.

> **Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/time):**
>
> The  CSS data type denotes time dimensions expressed in seconds or milliseconds. They consists of a  immediately followed by the unit. Like for any CSS dimension, there is no space between the unit literal and the number.

---

**Less** - The below is the Less code that you are using to set the delay value.

```
animation-delay         : @delay s;
```

**Compiled CSS** - When the above Less code is compiled you will get the below CSS.

```
animation-delay: 2 s;
```

As you have a space in the above line, output CSS also has an extra space in between the numeric and unit. This causes an issue even though the actual math operation is working properly. The below snippet uses the CSS generated by your original code.

```css
.intro-items:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5 s;
  animation-delay: 0.5 s;
}
.intro-items:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1 s;
  animation-delay: 1 s;
}
.intro-items:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5 s;
  animation-delay: 1.5 s;
}
.intro-items:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2 s;
  animation-delay: 2 s;
}
.intro-items {
  -webkit-animation: move 2s forwards;
  animation: move 2s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='intro-items'>Some text</div>
<div class='intro-items'>Some text</div>
<div class='intro-items'>Some text</div>
<div class='intro-items'>Some text</div>
```

---

**What is the solution?**

There are a few possible solutions to avoiding the space in between and they are as follows:

**Option 1** - Multiply with 1s

```
.animation-delay(@delay) {
  -webkit-animation-delay : @delay * 1s;
  animation-delay : @delay * 1s;
}
```

**Option 2** - Use the built-in `unit()` function

```
.animation-delay(@delay) {
  -webkit-animation-delay : unit(@delay,s);
  animation-delay         : unit(@delay,s);
}
```

**Option 3** - Instead of multiplying or converting the output value, add the units in the multiplier itself.

```
.generate-delay(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .intro-items:nth-child(@{i}) {
    .animation-delay(@i*.5s) /* note the addition of unit */
  }
  .generate-delay(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

**Option 4** - You could set the unit in the index (`@i`) variable itself (credits to [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070137/how-loop-work-in-less/32070407#comment52039142_32070407))

```
.generate-delay(@n, @i: 1s) when (@i =< @n) {
  .intro-items:nth-child(@{i}) {
    .animation-delay(@i*0.5)
  }
  .generate-delay(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

The below snippet is created using the CSS produced by using one of the above Less code.

```css
.intro-items:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.intro-items:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.intro-items:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.intro-items:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.intro-items {
  -webkit-animation: move 2s forwards;
  animation: move 2s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='intro-items'>Some text</div>
<div class='intro-items'>Some text</div>
<div class='intro-items'>Some text</div>
<div class='intro-items'>Some text</div>
```

Comment: There's 3rd option, index may have a unit [too](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/0afbf70cc68ef5e6e8fe). Though in this particular case I suppose the unit is better to be added with the `.5` multiplier itself (since semantically it's the most accurate code -> "each next element is delayed by .5**s** more").

Comment: @seven-phases-max Yeah, realized the multiplication bit just now and wow I never knew we could add units to the index. Thanks for that :) Will update the answer now.